# cin fail flag for putting strings into ints

Tags: c++, error-handling, casting, cin

I need to read in an int from the user using cin but print an error message if a string is entered instead. I have been trying to make it work using an if statement with `cin.fail()` which works well if only characters are entered. However, if the user enters something like `3sadi` it seems to read in the 3 and leave the rest of the string in the buffer, which doesn't give me the error message because the cin.fail() flag isn't set. How can I make it so that the error message is still printed if the first character of a string is an int?

```
int i1;
cin >> i1;
if (cin.fail() == true) {
    cout << "error" << endl; 
}
else{
    cout << "success" << endl;
}
```

eg. `32` should (and does) print success

`red` should (and does) print error

`3x` should print error but is printing success and leaving x in the buffer

How can I make `3x` give me the error message? Alternatively I could read it in as a string and cast it to an int and print out the message based on if it failed or succeeded but how do you use type cast errors in a program?

Comment: Don't you mean `int s1` instead of `string`?

Comment: yea sorry. changed it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formatted input of an numeric values succeeds is there is a prefix which contains digits. The streams won't easily allow you to change that behavior (you *can* change that behavior by using a specialized `std::num_get<char>` facet but I won't classify that as simple). The easiest approach is probably to check whether the next character (if there is one) happens to be a space (and don't use `fail()`; you should just use the conversion to a boolean value):

```
if (std::cin && (std::isspace(std::cin.peek()) || std::cin.eof())) {
    ...
}
```

Also, *don't* compare boolean values in conditions to `true` or `false`: the result doesn't become more boolean by doing so.